# How do I make permalinks available in a draft WordPress Post Preview

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

My permalink structure might be
     /%category%/%postname%

In a draft post I might want a "SEO friendly" internal link

```
<li><a href="http://dansblog.dan/cloud/Getting-started-with-azure/#item-one">Item One</a></li>
```

However when I preview to test my links, they will not work as my permalink is not available until publish time - even though it can be shown in my edit panel.

```
 http://dansblog.dan/?p=123&preview=true
```

So how can I make the permalink available in a daft post.

note  this works fine :-(

```
<li><a href="#item-one">Item One</a></li>
```

Daniel

Comment: In the end I have tested all my links with without the permalink in draft mode and added the full path to each url in the final draft. Just have to test when published